# How to code adding a total of all months balances in savings account program

Tags: java

My program in Java works but I am not sure how to get a total balance of both accounts. Right now I have it just printing out #####.

This should be the output:

Final balance of both accounts combined: 5255.81

I don't want to just type in the answer. We have to show the program adding all the balances of both accounts but I'm not sure how to write that code.

Here is my driver:

```
 public class LineberryRaeChapter13Prog {
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
   LRSavingsAccount saver1 = new LRSavingsAccount( 2000 );
   LRSavingsAccount saver2 = new LRSavingsAccount( 3000 );
   LRSavingsAccount.newInterestRate( 0.05 );

   System.out.println( "\nMonthly balances for one year with 0.05 annual interest:\n" );
   System.out.printf( "%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s\n", "Month", "Account#", "Balance", "Account#", "Balance" );
   System.out.printf( "%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s\n", "-----", "--------", "-------", "--------", "-------" );
   System.out.printf( "%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s\n", "0","10002", saver1.toString(), "10003", saver2.toString());

   for ( int month = 1; month <= 12; month++ )
   {
    switch (month)
    {
     case 1:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 2:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 3:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 4:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 5:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 6:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 7:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 8:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 9:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 10:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 11:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
     case 12:System.out.printf( "\n");
     break;
    }//end switch

 String monthLabel = String.format( "%d", month );
 saver1.addMonthlyInterest();
 saver2.addMonthlyInterest();

 System.out.printf( "%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s\n", monthLabel, "10002",    saver1.toString(), "10003", saver2.toString());
 }//end for

 System.out.printf( "%10s%10s\n", "\nFinal balance of both accounts  combined:", "######");
 }//end main
}//end LineberryRaeChapter13Prog
```

Here is the class:

```
public class LRSavingsAccount
{
  // interest rate for all accounts

 private static double annualInterestRate = 0;
private double Balance;
public static void newInterestRate( double newRate )
{
 annualInterestRate = (newRate >= 0 && newRate <= 1.0 ) ? newRate : 0.05;
}//end newInterestRate

// provides account balances

public LRSavingsAccount( double balance )
{
Balance = balance;
}//end Constructor

// calculates the interest for each month

public void addMonthlyInterest()
{
Balance += Balance * ( annualInterestRate / 12.0 );
}//end addMonthlyInterest

// get string representation of SavingAccount

public String toString()
{
 return String.format( "$%.2f", Balance );
 }//end accesssor

 }//end SavingsAccount
```

Comment: Add code for LRSavingsAccount. or you could user Double.parseDouble(saver1.toString()) + Double.parseDouble(saver2.toString())

Comment: Can you also provide the implementation of `LRSavingsAccount`?  I think this would be as simple as something like `saver1.getBalance() + saver2.getBalance()`, but I don't know if there is such a method.

Comment: You must edit your post and put the class LRSavingsAccount. Also, what's the deal with that switch you have?

Comment: Ok, I updated my post with the class LRSavingsAccount.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it you can add a getter in `LRSavingsAccount` for the Balance field. 
so

`public double getBalance() {
return Balance;
}`

And in the end, you could just do

`System.out.println(Final balance of both accounts  combined:" + (saver1.getBalance() + saver2.getBalance());`

Unless i'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks Austin. I did the system.out.println you have above and of course it wasn't working because I forgot the step to add it to my class code. Thanks again.